# Plot a date in x-axis in dhtmlxChart(DhtmlxSuite library)

Tags: date, dhtmlx

I am trying to work with DHTMLxChart and display the date values in x-axis.
Input is in Date format origDate= "Sat Jul 02 08:30:00 EDT 2016".
which I tried to format as String

DateFormat 
  formatter          = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
String date          = formatter.format(origDate); (02/07/16)

I tried implementing the below template to display the date in x-axis:

```
xAxis:{
template:function(obj){
return dhtmlx.Date.date_to_str("%d/%m/%Y")(obj.$unit);
},
value: function (obj) {
return dhtmlx.Date.str_to_date("%m/%d/%Y")(obj.date);
},
units:{
  start:new Date(2016,5,29),
  end:new Date(2016,6,10),
  next:function(d){
    return  dhtmlx.Date.add(d, 1, "day");
   }
  }
}
```

In spite of that it calculates the date values as “0.01756222” (performs division of 02/07/16) and throws an error- “Uncaught TypeError: date.split is not a function”.

I am not able to understand why the date value is calculated.

Answer (score 0):

xAxis configuration looks correct. Probably "date" properties of data items are not correct. Try to check that "obj.date" in "value" method is a string in "%m/%d/%Y" format.